# UISegmentedControl not showing when used with Map View

Tags: ios, storyboard, mkmapview, uisegmentedcontrol, uistoryboard

Anyone knows how I can get the UISegmentedControl to overlap with the MapView and still display properly? I'm currently trying to get a UISegmentedControl to appear in from of a MKMapView for users to switch the map type. I attached screenshots below.

This is my story board. Notice that the "Map View Controller Scene" clearly shows that the segmented control is above the Map View layer.
[image]

When I run the app with this storyboard setup, the UISegmentedControl does not appear.
[image]

Now i did manage to make it appear, only if I make sure that the uisegmentedcontrol does NOT overlap with the MapView.

This is the same story board, but this time, no overlap exists between the UISegmentedControl and the MapView
[image]

The app running, clearly showing the UISegmentedControl at the bottom
[image]

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"This is my story board. Notice that the "Map View Controller Scene" clearly shows that the segmented control is above the Map View layer."

I think you really want it AFTER the Map View for the z-order to be correct.

Reverse the order of the MapView and the UISegmentedControl, i.e. drag the segmented control to below/after the Map View in your Map View Controller Scene

Comment: ha! correct. for some reason, I had assumed that views behave like layers in photoshop/illustrator...etc and that the higher most is the one with the highest z-index. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but for me the difficulty was not the Z ordering. It was that my struts were not set properly. I had the top strut turned on, which was pushing it below the bottom of the viewable area in landscape orientation.